# How do I add tweets containing emoticons to my page without corrupting the rest of the page?

Tags: perl, twitter, character-encoding

My database stores data encoded as utf-8.

The top of my web page declares the character set:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>    
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

This webpage displays a field from the database which contains the symbol £ and the word ᴘʟâce (this is an unusual font). These both display correctly.

I'm now adding tweets to the page using Twitter::API in perl.

```
sub {
  use Twitter::API;
  my $twitteruser=shift;
  my $client = Twitter::API->new_with_traits(
        traits => 'Enchilada',
        consumer_key=>"",
        consumer_secret=>"",
        access_token=>"",
        access_token_secret=>"",
  );
  $tweets=$client->user_timeline("$twitteruser");
  return {Tweets=>$tweets}
}
```

When I add the tweets to the page, they display correctly on the page, but the field from the database has changed so the £ now displays as Â£ and the word ᴘʟâce now displays as `á´ÊÃ¢á´`
The only thing I've changed is adding the tweets. If I turn off the tweets, the page goes back to displaying correctly. If I only show tweets which have no strange characters in them, the page displays correctly. It is only displaying twitter usernames which are in a strange font or emoticons in the tweets which seem to cause the problem.

I checked the headers which show: `content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`

I found this [Saving Emoticons/Unicode from Twitter to a MySQL Database](https://andy-carter.com/blog/saving-emoticons-unicode-from-twitter-to-a-mysql-database) which seems to say that to save emoticons and unicode to MySQL the character set and collation properties of the table need changing. But I don't think this can be the solution as the characters are displayed correctly when pulled from the the database if the tweets are not added to the page. I've also tried pasting an emoticon into the text of the page. It displays correctly if I don't display the problem tweets. If I do, the emoticon is displayed as ð. So it doesn't seem to be a database problem. Somehow, adding the tweets to the page is corrupting the rest of the page, even though the tweets are displaying correctly.

I've been banging my head against the wall for a few days now. Can anyone help with some suggestions to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Tip: Just pass in `$x` instead of `"$x"` to functions, the quotes serve no purpose here.

Comment: You need to check that *everything* is UTF-8, from your database to the field, to the connection encoding to your client. Anything in that chain that's not UTF-8 causes [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake). If you're using MySQL you also need `utf8mb4` encoding to add support for 4-byte UTF-8 characters.

Comment: Do you use `mysql_enable_utf8mb4 => 1` on the connection used to write to the database? Do you use `mysql_enable_utf8mb4 => 1` on the connection used to read from database? Did you add an `:encoding(UTF-8)` later the file handle to which the web page is output?

Comment: The first thing you need to do is find out where things went wrong. A good place to start would be by using phpMyAdmin to check if the data is correct in the DB. (You could possibly use some existing other tool, but I can vouch for phpMyAdmin, so I'd use that if it's available.)

Comment: Another tool you can use is `sprintf("%vX", $str)`. If you get a string that includes `C2.A3`, something wasn't decoded as it should have been. If you get a string that includes `A3` without the leading `C2`, you have `£` as expected.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies and tips. I think I've made it too complicated by bringing the database into it. Looking at it again, I can can remove the database from the problem completely. If I just have a page which only shows an emoticon and then add the tweets, the emoticon is corrupted. Without adding the tweets the emoticon displays correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed it by adding

use encoding 'utf8';

to my perl subroutine. 
I'm not sure why this fixed it but happy that it did.